# Finding cube roots of $1$ in Cartesian form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here is the question: Find the $3$ cube roots of $1$. Give your answer in Cartesian form.
Hint: Write $1$=$e^{i\theta}$,$e^{-2\pi}$,$e^{i4\pi}$
 Is Cartesian form the same as rectangular form?
If so then I think I know the answer for $e^{i\theta}$.
 correct me if I am wrong, Is $e^{i\theta}$=$e^\frac{i\pi}{3}$,$e^{i\pi}$,$e^\frac{i5\pi}{3}$ in Cartesian form?
I do not know the other two. Need help.
Also if made any errors typing this, sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the $3$ cube roots of unity are the roots of $z^3=1 \iff (z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0\,$. The first factor gives $z=1\,$, and the second one is a simple quadratic, easy to solve for the other two roots.

Comment: Is my $e^{i\theta}$ correct?

Comment: $z=e^{i \pi /3}$ is not a cube root of unity since $z^3=e^{i \pi}=-1 \ne 1\,$ (and neither are the other two). The cube roots of unity are $e^{i \,2k\pi/3}$ for $k=0,1,2$ in polar form (but since you asked about the Cartesian form, it's easier to derive them from the equation $z^3=1$ directly).

Comment: Okay. I was using the hint giving to me, so I used that $e^{i\theta} to find its Cartesian form.  I will take your advice

Comment: @LadyT You can do it either way, but if you *do* use the polar form then make sure to get the $\theta$ right. $e^{i\theta}$=$e^\frac{i\pi}{3}$,$e^{i\pi}$,$e^\frac{i5\pi}{3}$ are the cube roots of $-1$, not $1\,$.

Comment: oh. I just checked that. thanks